# check select linq query from folder and database

Tags: database, linq

I have a folder in a directory that have pdf files with the names like this
23015.pdf
23221.pdf
.
.
etc

And I have database table with the primary key the same as the title of pdf files.
This table has name `Schools` and has following fields:

i. `SchoolUnit`: primary key number

ii. `SchoolName`: text

This table is filled with data as presented below:

```
SchoolUnit      SchoolName

23015            any name

23221            any name
```

I want to use linq to select pdf files from folder that have name with the same School table from database with the primary key the same.

I use this query:

```
var c = (
                 from i in di.GetFiles("*.pdf", SearchOption.AllDirectories).AsEnumerable()
                 let scu = Int32.Parse(System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(i.Name))
                 from s in db.GetTable<Schools>().AsEnumerable()
                 where scu == s.SchoolUnit 
                 select new { i, s, scu }
                 );
```

I am choosing pdf folder by using browse dialog (its not constant folder directory). If I choose any folder that does not have pdf files which I need, I want to display error that it is not the correct folder that has pdf files.

Comment: And the question is.. ?

Comment: please provide what error you exactly getting

Comment: Exception thrown: 'System.FormatException' in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format.